# python 3.5 + aiohttp: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when use io.BytesIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, aiohttp

example i send file

```
with open('test_zip'), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
res = requests.post(URL, data={'file': content})
```

And then I try to get the file on the server side

```
async def handle(request):
    form = await request.post()
    data = io.BytesIO((form['file']))
    with open('test_zip_2', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(data)
```

And an error occurs, but I can open a new archive with Ubuntu

> data = io.BytesIO((form['file'])) TypeError: a bytes-like object is
>   required, not 'str'

Comment: My guess is that `form['file']` is of type `str`.  Try passing `form['file'].encode('ascii')` instead, as it utilizes the byte array of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert [FileField](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.FileField) to `io.BytesIO` at all.

Use [`FileField.file.read()`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.FileField.file) to get file content:

```
async def handle(request):
    form = await request.post()
    with open('test_zip_2', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(form['file'].file.read())
```

See [**File Uploads** part - aio documentation](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web.html#file-uploads).